# Javascript : Why can't I use the "this" with childnodes?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="test" onmouseover="working(this)">
<p>help</p>
<p>me</p>
</div>

<div id="test" onmouseover="not_working(this)">
<p>help</p>
<p>me</p>
</div>
```

When I use the first function(not_working) it doesn't work, but when I used the second function(working) it does.

```
function not_working(element){
document.getElementById(element).childNodes[1].innerHTML="succeed";}

function working(element){
document.getElementById("test").childNodes[1].innerHTML="succeed";}
```

Sorry if I miss something simple, I'm still learning html and only have limited knowledge on javascript.

Comment: `this` is not an ID. It's an element.

Comment: You have used the element in for getting the ele using getElementById. Which is wrong. (You need to pass only string in this selector).

Comment: Use like this "document.getElementById(element.id).childNodes[1].innerHTML="succeed";}" with unique ID to resolve it.

Comment: @INDRAJITH why? What is the point to get *the element*, then get its ID, in order to find *the same element*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the element, the event was created from (the div in your case), but `getElementById` takes an id (`"test"` in your case).

Also the hovered element is already being passed in the function as `element` so you can just do:

```
function working(element) {
    element.childNodes[1].innerHTML="succeed"
}
```